# Authentication of LDAP queries with Windows Authentication under IIS

Tags: authentication, iis, vbscript, ldap

I have to write a webpage which is used to change the AD password. The page is hosted with an IIS server. I only have the old code which is an over 10 years old .asp page written in VisualBasicScript and got patched multiple times. The actual problem is that I get an 80040E37 Error when trying to query a user object, which implies that I don't have the permission to query the data.

I figured out that the problem is gone when I explicit use a user/password when creating an establishing the ADOConnection. But I don't want to hardcode credentials and in the old version it is not done either.
I am authenticated in some way, because I can query a user with:

```
Set objSysInfo = Server.CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUserName = objSysInfo.UserName
```

It is the same user which works hardcoded.
I do not know if this is a coding problem or an IIS configuartion problem.

I extracted the following code from the old version (except the commented out lines):

```
Dim adoConnection
Set adoConnection = createObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
'adoConnection.Properties("User ID") = "USER"
'adoConnection.Properties("Password") = "PASSWORD"
'adoConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
adoConnection.Open

Dim adoCommand
set adoCommand = createObject("ADODB.Command")

Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection
adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100

adoCommand.CommandText = "LDAPQUERY"
Dim adRecSet
set adRecSet = createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
adRecSet.open adoCommand
```

I would expect ( and do get it if I uncomment the 3 lines) a valid result object; I get an Error:

> An operations error occurred.
>   80040E37

How do I query data with the user configured in the IIS server?